# Cannot import maven project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When trying to open a maven project through the `pom.xml`, IntelliJ shows the windows: `Open project`, when I click open as project I can see the window: `scanning maven projects`. I can't get to the window open in current window or new window.

When I try to open a non-maven project, it opens it. When I try to open a maven project as a normal project it doesn't seem to do anything.

I have successfully opened a project as maven project through cloning it from Git, bit it gives me errors that it can't import the maven dependencies.

I can do `mvn --version`, `mvn clean compile` etc.

I have tried to open projects without the `.idea` folder and with the `.idea` folder. That didn't work.

I have reinstalled IntelliJ already.

EDIT: I am using IntelliJ version: 2018.2.4 Ultimate.

EDIT2: I just noticed that the blue color that usually appears by a pom.xlm is different, see screenshot.[other color?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtPkY.png)

Comment: you have to Enable auto import maven.. In the right bottom corner of IntelliJ , there is a Event Log tab. when you click it It might be show you the option Enable auto import. Or manually you have to enable Auto import by go to the settings.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: The auto import popup never appears

Comment: @mrmannione See edit, I use IntteliJ Ultimate 2018.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an exception in your firewall so IntelliJ can make http requests?

Answer (score 1):

To import a maven based project in intellij Idea follow the following steps:

> Open intellij idea,
>   Goto File menu,
>   Click on New,
>   Click on Project from existing sources,
>   Select file or directory to import,
>   Select POM file ,
>   Click on OK,
>   Finalize the other steps, 
>   wait till the  import loading gets completed(Sometime it takes much duration to complete)
>   Your project will get loaded with files and folder on left side.